# Xamarin android populate listview from VB.net webservice

Tags: c#, vb.net, web-services, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am new to Xamarin and Android programming.

I am trying to populate a list view with a method from a VB.net webservice. The webservices is refrenced into the Xamarin project

My code for the webservice is

```
<WebMethod()>
    Public Function GetJobs() As ArrayList
        Dim lt As ArrayList
        For i = 0 To 25
            lt.Add("Item DB " & i)
        Next
        Return lt
    End Function
```

I just wanted to generate a list of items. Eventually records from a DB

This is my code for the android part in C#

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Dashboard);
        // Create your application here

        WebserviceConnector.WebserviceConnector myServ = new WebserviceConnector.WebserviceConnector();

        myServ.Url = "http://192.168.0.17/dsc1/WebserviceConnector.asmx";

        listnames = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView1);
        //itemlist = new List<string>();

        ArrayAdapter<string> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, myServ.GetJobs());
        listnames.Adapter = adapter;
        listnames.ItemClick += Listnames_ItemClick;

    }
```

I dont know if im going in the wrong direction here but I am new to webservices and Android programming and I would really appreciate some guidance.

Thanks

Comment: have you read the docs?  https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/

Comment: Yes but they are not very clear. I am looking at possible outputting the data as JSON from the web service then interpretting that via the app but it is very confusing.